# Cannot unzip a file from gdrive

Tags: google-apps-script, unzip

i am trying to unzip a folder in a gdrive folder. I tried with different folders. Original one gets downloaded from my gmail and contains an xlsx file, and then also tried with a folder with jpg in it that i uploaded to the gdrive. with both I don't get any errors, i see "unzipping completed" in the execution log, however no folders get unzipped.

```
 var folderId = "Folder_ID"; 

 // Fetch the folder contents using the Google Drive API
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
 var files = folder.getFiles();

 // Create an empty array to store the blobs of the files in the folder
 var blobs = [];

 // Iterate through each file in the folder and add its blob to the blobs array
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   blobs.push(file.getBlob());
 }

 // zip now references a blob containing an archive of all the files in the folder
 var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, "folder_contents.zip");
 Logger.log(zip);

 // This now unzips the blobs
 var unzippedFiles = Utilities.unzip(zip);

 // Output the names of the unzipped files
 for (var i = 0; i < unzippedFiles.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(unzippedFiles[i].getName());
 }
 
 Logger.log("Unzipping completed.");
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `however no folders get unzipped.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but on the code there file first gets zipped here:

```js
 // Iterate through each file in the folder and add its blob to the blobs array
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   blobs.push(file.getBlob());
 }

 // zip now references a blob containing an archive of all the files in the folder
 var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, "folder_contents.zip");
```

And then it tries to get unzipped here:

```js
 // This now unzips the blobs
 var unzippedFiles = Utilities.unzip(zip);

 // Output the names of the unzipped files
 for (var i = 0; i < unzippedFiles.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(unzippedFiles[i].getName());
 }
```

The problem with this section of the code is that although it is accessing the zip file's data it is only printing the names of the files, instead here is a working code that goes right to the unzipping and places the files it found in a specific folder:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("target folder ID")
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("file ID").getBlob()
  file.setContentType("application/zip")
  var unzipped = Utilities.unzip(file)
//Logger.log(unzipped[0])
  for(var i=0; i<unzipped.length; i++)
  {
    DriveApp.createFile(unzipped[i]).moveTo(folder)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code and now it opens the xlsx  directly from the attachment. I couldn't find a way unzip the file though. So it is just a workaround.